# Helpful flags - does second count?

Tags: support, helpful-flags, flag-badges

For the helpful flags, of the Deputy badge, if a post is flagged already, for the same cause or different cause, when I flag it, does it count towards my flag score?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not matter what other flags are raised on the same post. As long as your flag is marked helpful, it counts toward helpful flag total and badges. There are multiple ways in which a flag can be marked helpful: see [Why does flag marking as helpful/declined not always correlate with moderator action?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105391/why-does-flag-marking-as-helpful-declined-not-always-correlate-with-moderator-ac) for example.